# Why would accessing a random access file be crashing the Java platform?

Tags: java, file

Edit, resolved:
Resolution:

Step 1: Ensured seek methods went to the correct locations and written with the correct byte length. Fixed several seek misdirections.

Step 2: Updated java and jgrasp to latest versions. Fixed java crash but began receiving major-minor mismatch error.

Step 3: Went to the jgrasp control shell, opened start-up settings and selected the upgraded jre
Error Resolved

---

I'm writing a program to read and write a custom object (patient) to a random access file. At the moment though I'm just writing the individual components(two strings, 3 integers, and a double) to the file rather then the object itself. It worked fine for a bit and everything still compiles but then I started getting java.exe crash messages after I implemented the writePatientWeight. I've tried commenting out the new methods but it still crashes.

```
   import java.io.*; 
   public class randomTest extends randomAccessMethods{
   public static void main (String args[])throws IOException{
     RandomAccessFile test=createNewFile("test", "rw");
     writePatientID(test, 1234567891);
     writePatientFName(test, "Derrick");
     writePatientLName(test, "Hollenbeck");
     writePatientAge(test, 18);
     writePatientRisk(test, 10);
     writePatientWeight(test, 155);
     test.seek(0);
     int i=test.readInt();
     System.out.println(i);
     test.seek(40);
     String fname=test.readUTF();
     System.out.println(fname);
     test.seek(57);
     String lname=test.readUTF();
     System.out.println(lname);
     test.seek(81);
     int age=test.readInt();
     System.out.println(age);
     test.seek(93);
     int risk=test.readInt();
     System.out.println(risk);
     test.seek(101);
     double weight=test.readDouble();
     System.out.println(weight);
  }
}
```

The randomAccessMethods class:

```
   import java.io.*;
public class randomAccessMethods extends CriticalPatientQueue{
  public static RandomAccessFile createNewFile(String name, String readwrite) throws IOException{
     if(readwrite!= "r"){//insures that there is a usable read/write variable, defaults to "rw" if there isn't
        if(readwrite!= "w"){
           if(readwrite!= "rw"){
              readwrite="rw";
           }
        }
     }
     RandomAccessFile file=new RandomAccessFile(name+".dat", readwrite);
     return file;
  }

  public static void writePatientID(RandomAccessFile file, int id)throws IOException{
     file.seek(0);  
     file.writeInt(id);//writes the ID to the file, uses 40 bytes(id will always be length 10)
  }

  public static void writePatientFName(RandomAccessFile file, String fname)throws IOException{
     file.seek(40);
     file.writeUTF(fname);//writes the name to the file, uses 17 bytes(fname will always be length 15 + 2 for overhead)
     for(int i=0; i<(17-fname.length()); i++){
        file.writeUTF(" ");
     }
  }

  public static void writePatientLName(RandomAccessFile file, String lname)throws IOException{
     file.seek(57);
     file.writeUTF(lname);//writes the name to the file, uses 24 bytes(fname will always be length 22 + 2 for overhead)
     for(int i=0; i<(22-lname.length()); i++){
        file.writeUTF(" ");
     }
  }

  public static void writePatientAge(RandomAccessFile file, int age)throws IOException{
     file.seek(81);  
     file.writeInt(age);//writes the age to the file, uses 12 bytes(age will always be length 3)
  }

  public static void writePatientRisk(RandomAccessFile file, int risk)throws IOException{
     file.seek(93);  
     file.writeInt(risk);//writes the risk value to the file, uses 8 bytes(risk will always be length 2)
  }

  public static void writePatientWeight(RandomAccessFile file, double weight)throws IOException{
     file.seek(101);
     file.writeDouble(weight);//writes the weight to the file, uses 24 bytes(weight will always be length 3 for overhead) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your crash come with a stack trace?

Comment: What do you mean "crashes"? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I get a java.exe crash with the following message: java.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: And you are using an up to date version of Java?  Can you post the stack trace in the crash report?

Comment: Up to date on this computer, going to try on my home computer when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made some assumption that just aren't true.  When you write an `int` it will always take the same number of bytes.  For example:

```
public static void writePatientAge(RandomAccessFile file, int age)throws IOException{
 file.seek(81);  
 file.writeInt(age);//writes the age to the file, uses 12 bytes(age will always be length 3)
}
```

In fact, an int will always use 4 bytes when written out like this.  See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeInt%28int%29).

> Writes an int to the file as four bytes, high byte first. The write starts at the current position of the file pointer.

I would guess that errors of this kind result in the problems you are seeing.  You should replace all your constants and seeks with the appropriate values (e.g. assume an `int` is 4 bytes everywhere you use writeInt, similarly `double` is eight bytes).

Comment: Changed it to implement this(ints are 4 bytes, doubles are 8 bytes now), still crashes. Example of new method (apologies, still learning the formatting here):     `public static void writePatientFName(RandomAccessFile file, String fname)throws IOException{
         file.seek(4);
         file.writeUTF(fname);//writes the name to the file, uses 17 bytes(fname will always be length 15 + 2 for overhead)
         for(int i=0; i<(17-fname.length()); i++){
            file.writeUTF(" ");
         }
      }`

Comment: Same issue I'd guess but for `file.writeUtf` (see Peter Lawrey's answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Without the stack trace from the crash its hard to speculate.  I would try Java 6 update 30 or Java 7 update 2 to ensure its not a bug in your JVM.

---

You need to understand how many bytes each field will actually use.

int always uses 4 bytes.

writeUTF() writes 2 bytes for the length followed by the String UTF-8 encoded.  This means some characters use 2 and 3 bytes.  If you are using seek() there is no point padding the end of the field as far as I can see. `writeUTF(" ")` writes three bytes.

I wouldn't use so many magic numbers,  try to keep your constants in one place and use offsets from a base location so you can have more than one record.

Finally, I use memory mapped files as it can be 30x faster.  This is because you can avoid making a system call on each field (you only have a system call which you map the byte buffer)  I use a List of 1 GB ByteBuffers (the largest power of 2 an `int` can have)

Here is an example where I create an 8 TB file memory mapped. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-memory-mapped-file-for-huge.html

Using this approach you can read/write a record which is persisted to disk in 50 - 200 ns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [serialization/deseralization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) instead of writing/reading each field independently. Through this technique you may write and read object into/from the disk file.

Comment: Looking into it, [this](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/serializationFAQ.jsp#random) says I can't directly write objects using it to a random access file. I'm required to use random access files as it's a school project, but I'll look into using the non-direct method.